# Disabling a form based on the other form's input

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am currently working on **2 drop down forms**, say `form1` and `form2`. I have a certain list of values in `form1` clicking which `form2` would be disabled and for some it would not be disabled. I am working on Angular 4 with TypeScript. Any place where I could start figuring out how to achieve this?

**Below is my form code**

```
  <div class="form-group" style="width: 350px">
      <label for="form_periodicity"><b>Periodicity</b></label><br>
      <select class="form-control" id="periodicity" style="width: 222px">
        <option>EOD</option>
        <option>Daily</option>
        <option>Weekly</option>
        <option>Monthly</option>
        <option>Strict run</option>
      </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group" style="width: 350px">
      <label for="form_timeofexecution"><b>Time of execution</b></label><br>
      <select class="form-control" id="timeofexecution" style="width: 222px">
        <option>0:00</option>
        <option>0:30</option>
        <option>1:00</option>
        <option>4:00</option>
        <option>5:00</option>
      </select>
  </div>
```

So I want to disable the **second form** group when **Strict run** is selected from the **first form**.

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: @AmitChigadani Added the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In first select you can fire an function which will work on change event like this

```
<select class="form-control" id="periodicity" (change)="onChange($event)" style="width: 222px">
  <option>EOD</option>
  <option>Daily</option>
  <option>Weekly</option>
  <option>Monthly</option>
  <option value="0">Strict run</option>
</select>
```

and in ts file define a boolean variable and change its value on change event like this

```
disableSelect:bolean
 onChange(e){
 let chosen= parseInt((<HTMLSelectElement>e.srcElement).value);
 if(chosen.value==0){
  this.disableSelect=true;
   return;
 }
this.disableSelect=false;
}
```

and in your second select bind that boolean variable like this

```
<select class="form-control" id="dayofexecution" [disabled]="disableSelect" style="width: 222px">
```

Comment: I tried your solution but it does not log in the value pertaining to Strict date.

Comment: I am not able to understand where my code breaks can you explain it further

Comment: It does not understand $event parameter in onChange function.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a simple JS event listener.

I assume this is what you wanna do:

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
  document.getElementById('periodicity').addEventListener('click', function(e){
    if(e.target.value == 'Strict run' )
      document.getElementById('dayofexecution').disabled = true;
    else
      document.getElementById('dayofexecution').disabled = false;
  })
});
```

```html
  <div class="form-group" style="width: 350px">
      <label for="form_periodicity"><b>Periodicity</b></label><br>
      <select class="form-control" id="periodicity" style="width: 222px">
        <option>EOD</option>
        <option>Daily</option>
        <option>Weekly</option>
        <option>Monthly</option>
        <option>Strict run</option>
      </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group" style="width: 350px">
      <label for="form_dayofexecution"><b>Time of execution</b></label><br>
      <select class="form-control" id="dayofexecution" style="width: 222px">
        <option>0:00</option>
        <option>0:30</option>
        <option>1:00</option>
        <option>4:00</option>
        <option>5:00</option>
      </select>
  </div>
```